# Undocumented .NET code related to Multi-Touch Manipulations throwing exception

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, multi-touch

A favorable outcome would be preventing this exception, preferably, or at least handling it gracefully.

I am getting an exception thrown *within* Microsoft code. On top of that, the method throwing the exception is `System.Windows.Input.Manipulations.ManipulationSequence.ProcessManipulators`, which I can't find in Microsoft Reference Source.

When the exception is thrown, I can see that one line down in the Call Stack window it references [`Windows.Input.Manipulations.ManipulationProcessor2D.ProcessManipulators`, which does exist in Microsoft Reference Source.](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Input.Manipulations/System/Windows/Input/Manipulations/ManipulationProcessor2D.cs)

But as you can see, it *doesn't* have a sibling class named `ManipulationSequence`.

As for the exception itself, it is a `System.Argument.OutOfRangeException` with a value of `Timestamp values must not decrease. Parameter name: timestamp Actual value was 6590630705479.`

The fully qualified signature of the method throwing the exception is `System.Windows.Input.Manipulations.ManipulationSequence.ProcessManipulators(long timestamp, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Windows.Input.Manipulations.Manipulator2D> manipulators, System.Windows.Input.Manipulations.ManipulationSequence.ISettings settings)`

It appears as if [one other person in the universe](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c006f4af-9c88-4f1c-9dca-07e83a8d3b43/manipulation-delta-event-throwing-exception-timestamp-values-must-not-decrease?forum=wpf) has had this problem, but it could not be reproduced according to the only comment.

I have 6 `MediaElement` objects on a canvas that are all running videos when being manipulated, so I feel as though it might have something to do with the CPU being taxed and slowing down, possibly making timestamps be sent into the method out of order (though the same problem occurs when using `Image` rather than `MediaElement`). The exception happens sporadically, sometimes it will happen after just a few seconds of messing around with the objects, sometimes it can go for a few minutes or more of manipulating the objects.

My code that does the actual manipulation within `ManipulationDelta`  looks like this:

```
//Get current values to manipulate
TransformGroup group = (TransformGroup)element.RenderTransform.Clone();
TranslateTransform translate = (TranslateTransform)group.Children[0].Clone();
ScaleTransform scale = (ScaleTransform)group.Children[1].Clone();
RotateTransform rotate = (RotateTransform)group.Children[2].Clone();

//...does manipulations on each by changing values...

//Apply transformation changes
group.Children[0] = translate;
group.Children[1] = scale;
group.Children[2] = rotate;
element.RenderTransform = group;
```

I have a `Storyboard` in XAML messing with the `RotateTransform`, so I can't really use `MatrixTransform`.

I am creating this using WPF with .NET 4.5.1. The error occurs in both Windows 8.1 and Windows 7. Any ideas on how to prevent this exception from occurring?

---

Some thoughts as I investigate the problem:

- I also have `ManipulationInertiaStarting` in play here as a possible 
  cause of this error.
- I just added `e.Handled = true;` to the end of `ManipulationCompleted`, which wasn't there before. I haven't got the error since (though, again, very sporadic, so it is hard to tell when it is fixed).
- If a `ManipulationDelta` method is not yet complete, and it is hit again from user input, could there be some sort of race condition occurring where the first method hit is starved for CPU resources and the second runs through, then when the first method finally completes the timestamp created is in the past?

  - Per a comment, this isn't likely.
- I conferred with a co-worker to gain better understanding. He helped me realize I can't swallow the exception from within my methods that handle manipulation events because the exception is happening before it gets there, in the actual creation of the manipulation data. So the only place I can handle the exception is on App.Main() (the first place in the Call Stack where my code exists), which makes handling it gracefully all the more difficult.

Comment: What type of touch input device are you using?  Are you doing anything else fancy like hooking into the input system (like the msdn forum link you posted does)?  Also, if you catch the exception to suppress it does it continue happening all the time or just sporadically?

Comment: Touch input is an Acer monitor, I believe the Acer T232HL. I'm not certain I understand what you mean by "hooking into the input system." Could you clarify? Also, I am not currently suppressing the exception, though I can do that. It might be an option if it happens sporadically, but of course I would love to solve the underlying cause.

Comment: Nothing *should* be getting out of order.  If the CPU is too busy to handle inputs, WPF is smart enough to drop "intermediate" events (older events in the queue) rather than making the situation worse.

Comment: Is it at all possible that something in the background is altering your system clock?

Comment: Anything's possible, but this happens both on my dev machine (Windows 8.1) and the test machine (Windows 7). The test machine is a stock install as far as I know, bar the application I'm putting on it.

Comment: Ok I'd like to look into this but am baffled.  I worked on the team the built these APIs and have never seen this issue.  If you can post a repro, I'll try to figure it out but based on what's here I'm stuck :(

Comment: Definitely thank you for your help thus far. I'll see what I can do to make this be reproducible (I myself and having trouble with that).

Comment: this looks ugly, no specific ideas as to why (if a team member can't help) but maybe an advice in similar situations - try to bring things down to a more simple scenario. With enough experimenting you usually get to a point where something turned on/off changes the behavior, so you can see what "may" be the problem. That it doesn't repeat well is a bitch, which makes it ugly

Comment: I am going to attempt to make it consistently reproducible this weekend.

Comment: At a guess I would say it is because you have storyboard and manual manipulation of transforms. Try running one or the other and see if error occurs

Comment: RenderTransform.Clone(); and applying clone to the element doesn't look good also especially if storyboard tries at same time,

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem myself.
After a lot of testing it could be reproduced with slower machines under heavy load.

The Application was for Digital Signage and showed a lot of different items ( Video, Html , Images , etc ) and had also some animations.

I am not sure about it but it seems to be a problem of handling the input events in time.

For myself i could "solve" this issue with outsourcing code from the manipulating to other code asynchronous and also profiling and rewriting code performance-wise.( shortened the path to run inside the event as much as possible and did everything needed to do also later with a Task )

Also i added an Exceptionhandler to my application to "ignore and log" this issue, because it had no other impact.

Feel free to contact me for more info on this.

PS: this is my first answer here, so i hope it is alright the way i wrote it

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems when developing for WinRT.

It's sometimes possible to use [DispatcherUnhandledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx) event to ignore one particular exception. To do that, add event listener, check if exception is the one you want (because it's generally bad idea to suppress all exception), and then set [Handled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherunhandledexceptioneventargs.handled.aspx) property.